# Custom CSS classes on Angular 2 component templates based on location

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Our team is migrating our codebase to Angular 2, and being in charge of CSS development/organization, I looked into the options for adding styles within Angular 2 as well as how Angular 2 could change the way we build our UI. Many of our UI elements will be components. One thing I'd like to do is add a custom CSS class to the parent element within a component's template depending on where it appears. Here's an example UI element:

```
<button class="basic-button">
    Some action text
</button>
```

This would live in a file called `basic-button.component.html`. Its component selector is `basic-button`. Let's say the button appears in a customer's account settings page, and the design requires a text color value different from our default. We'd like to add a modifier CSS class to the button element:

```
<button class="basic-button--alert basic-button">
    Some action text
</button>
```

But if the same button also appears in a product page and requires yet another color value, we need to apply a different modifier class:

```
<button class="basic-button--warning basic-button">
    Some action text
</button>
```

Is there a way to attach a custom class to the button element based on where it appears? It's important to apply the class to the actual HTML element since applying it to the component selector might not properly affect the style, as in this case the button's text color. For specific reasons we don't plan on scoping our CSS, so in theory we could use nesting to meet our goals:

```
.account-settings .basic-button {
    color: red;
}

.product-details .basic-button {
    color: orange;
}
```

But we prefer to minimize nesting as much as possible.

Comment: You could use `routes` to know which page of your app you're currently in and act accordingly with conditional classes https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route

Comment: You can use an @Input on your component and configure by this input which button it should be, use ngClass to change the css by the input value or create just few kind of elements inside this component and switch between them based on the input value. (I hope I understood what you wanted to achieve)

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using the [activated-route](http://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route) is good. I would create a custom button component with the button in it to which you can inherit the properties you want to apply and use [HostBinding](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/custom-directives/hostlistener-and-hostbinding/#_hostbinding) to apply the class on the custom component based on the activated route.

Or (for me it feels a bit hacky) you could create a directive which you can apply to the native button component and then use the Angular [Renderer](https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/) in order to apply the class on the button based on the activated route.